# jQuery onclick change html of closest div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use multiple instances of the same code snippet on the same page. This is a small image gallery, that changes out the image shown in a div based on the link clicked. I have everything working correctly, but when clicking the image to place in the div, it changes out every div on the page using that class. I tried using $(this).closest but that does not appear to be working at all. Am I close?

```
<div class="gallery-carousel">
  <div class="galleryImageChange">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icon-pager">
  <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="gallery-carousel">
  <div class="galleryImageChange">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icon-pager">
  <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
</div>

$('a.imageNav').click(function() {
    var $content = $(this).html();
    $(this).closest('div.galleryImageChange').html($content);
    return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, I have to use multiple instances of this, and I cannot use individual ID's for each one. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mc8eo8c6/10/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `.closest` will look for parent element of the `current-element`, as specified selector is not a parent of the `element`, nothing will be selected.

Use selector as `$(this).closest('.icon-pager').prev('div.gallery-carousel').find('div.galleryImageChange')`

```js
$('a.imageNav').click(function() {
  var $content = $(this).html();
  $(this).closest('.icon-pager').prev('div.gallery-carousel').find('div.galleryImageChange').html($content);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-carousel">
  <div class="galleryImageChange">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icon-pager">
  <a href="#" class="imageNav">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery-carousel">
  <div class="galleryImageChange">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icon-pager">
  <a href="#" class="imageNav">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="imageNav">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML like this

```
<div class="galleryContainer">
  <div class="gallery-carousel">
    <div class="galleryImageChange">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-pager">
    <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="galleryContainer">
  <div class="gallery-carousel">
    <div class="galleryImageChange">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-pager">
    <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
    <a href="#" class="imageNav"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
$('a.imageNav').click(function() {
    var $content = $(this).html();
    $(this).closest(".galleryContainer").find('div.galleryImageChange').html($content);
    return false;
});
```